# Compare times to a giving time in a cell

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BXyoQ.jpg)i would like some help in trying to create a formula that compares a certain time in 1 cell to the Current time.in the end, i would like that cell to highlight a color if it is less then or equal to then the current time.
For example:

Cell A2 has a time of 14:00, highlight this cell Red if it is less then or equal too than the Current time.

Comment: What is your issue? What steps have you done to achieve the goal and where did you stuck? Did you try conditional formatting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just enter the formula =TEXT(NOW(),"H:MM") and then just do a conditional format as formula to say, cell C4<=A2 or what ever cell ref you have.

The NOW formula will return Todays date and the current time. The text formula allows you to remove the date, and display the time how you want it. "H:MM" will still return military time. If you want to go to standard use "H:MM AM/PM".

[image: textnow]

[image: conditionalFormat]

---

UPDATE: Try using the below format for the cell, and in the conditional formatting formula =($H$9<=(NOW()-TODAY()))

This should match up your formatting with the now function.

[image: format]

[image]

As for wanting to be able to just type in the time without having to hit the colon. The only way I know how to do that is cell format as Other and 00:00. However this is not a time format and it messes with the conditional formatting. So you will need to find a work around

[image: Forward]

Comment: ok, so i tried this, but the cell is highlighted all the time. Would the format of the fixed time mess up the conditional format formula? i have tried a few different types but cant seem to get it to work.

Comment: Possibly formatting. Try posting a screen shot of your sheet or a mock up of the formula and I can try and help problem solve. Hard to know without seeing it.

Comment: i post a link in the original post. Sorry, i am brand new to this site! Hopefully that works.

Comment: I updated the answer, I think it is just a formatting issue. set it up with that format and you should be good to go. As for not having to type the colon for the time, you can do it but the conditional formatting will no longer work. I added how at the end as well.

Comment: PERFECT!!! ill circle back at a later time to the format i was trying use. Thank you!